# Can I use provisioning profile for Enterprise store and App store?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, enterprise, app-distribution

I have an iOS app that is currently deployed to the Enterprise store. Now I want to also distribute it to App Store. Can I use the same certificate and provisioning profile from Enterprise version, or do I have create new? Also what about the App-ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App-ID should be the same there is no need to change it. 
But you need to rebuild with a new production certificate and once when you created you will need to create a new provisioning profile.

Usually, this can be done automatically from xCode if you have the needed rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one distribution cer and same app-id to enterprise and appstore. But provisioning is diffirent type.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile cannot be used to build an app for the App Store.  You will need to get a new iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile to use for the build you submit to the app store.  The provisioning is very different so you cannot use the same one for both.